# Angular used before defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Been working on AngularJS but i am getting a error stating that Angular is being used before it was defined. I have watched over a few videos and gone through the docs. Even with just the first line in the js file i am getting the error. in the index file, i am calling angular 1.6.2 as the first file before anything else which is why i am confused as to why im being told its being used before being defined.

my html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="weatherApp">
  <head>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3 Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

      <div class="container">

          <div>
            <div id="web-api">
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the js is:

```
// MODULE - WEATHER
var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

weatherApp.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);

// ROUTING 
weatherApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home.htm',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })

});

weatherApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

weatherApp.controller('forecastController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it can help but did you try to move `ng-app` from `html` to `body` tag?

Comment: Have you tried including your `app.js` in the body instead of the head?

Comment: Load `angular-resource` and `angular-route` before `angular.js` file. Move angular files below jquery so that you can use jquey properties in angular files

Comment: Also some of your `<script src=` includes look off (missing `https:` at the beginning)

Comment: This sequence of including scripts should be correct. It works in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRPMvd)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any server environment. Please make sure you are running the angular routes under any server environment like live-server.

Also make sure the extension for the html file is correctly specified in the routing config in app.js

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your CDNs aren't set up correctly. Try these instead:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

Also according to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading), this is the recommended location, and should provide faster loading times.